# Why using innoDB and transactions?

Tags: php, mysql, database, transactions, innodb

So I wanted to start a browser game project. Just for practise.

After years of `PHP` programming, today I heard about `transactions` and `innoDB` the first time ever.

So I googled it and still have some questions.

My first encounter with it was on a website that says, InnoDB would be necessary when programming a browsergame. Because it might be used by many people at the same time and if two people access to a database table at the same time (with one nanosecond difference for example), it could get confusing and data might be lost or your `SELECT` is not updated although it should have been updated by the access one nanosecond ago (but the script was still running and couldn't change it yet) ... and so on.

And apparently, `transactions` solve this problem by first handling the first access (until it is completed) and then handling the second one. Is this correct?

And another function is, that if you have for example `2 queries` in your `transaction` and the second one fails, it "rolls back" and "deletes"(or never applies) the changes of the first (successful) `query`. Right? So either everything goes as it should or nothing changes at all. That would be great I think.

Another question: When should I use transactions? Everytime I access the database? Or is it better to use it just for some particular accesses to the database? And should I always use `try {} catch() {}`?

And one last question:
How does this transaction proceeds? 
My understanding is the following:

1. You start a `transaction`
2. You do your `queries` and change the `database` or `SELECT` something
3. If everything went well, you `commit` the changes so they get applied to the database
4. If something went wrong with `queries` it cancels and jumps to the `catch() {}` where you `rollback` the transaction and the changes don't get applied

Is this correct? Of course, besides the question how to `start`, `commit` and `rollback` a `transaction` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is correct.You can also create savepoints to save your current point before running the query.I stricly recommend you to look into the documentation of mysql references it is explained there clearly.